# Possible improvement in url scheme in a flask webapp

Tags: python, url, sqlalchemy, flask

I am creating a blog using Flask framework in python.

I have following view/url for displaying a post:

```
    @post_blueprint.route('/post/<int:year>/<int:month>/<title>', methods=['GET'])
    def get_post(year, month, title):
    try:
        title = title.replace('-', ' ')
        post = Post.query.filter(Post.title == title).one()
        post.comment_form = UserCommentForm()
    except NoResultFound:
        raise
    return render_template('show_single_post.html', post=post)
```

In above code, I am also passing a comment form which will let user post a comment. After that I wrote the view/url for receiving this post request:

```
    @post_blueprint.route('post/<int:post_id/comment/add/', mehtods=['POST'])
    def add_comment(post_id):
        post = Post.query.get(post_id)
        if not post:
            raise Exception
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCommentForm(request.form)
            if form.validate():
            try:
               user = User.query.\
                    filter(User.email == form.email.data).one()
            except NoResultFound:
               user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data,
                        form.website.data or None)

            try:
                comment = Comment(form.comment.data, post_id)
                comment.author = user
                db_session.add(comment)
                db_session.commit()
            except IntegrityError:
                 raise

            return redirect(url_for('.get_post', year=post.posted_on.year,
                                                 month=post.posted_on.month,
                                                 title=post.title.replace(' ','-')
                                    )
                            )
```

In above view, I am accessing post object from db to make sure post exists.
I create user if it does not exist and then I save the comment.

Now my problem is instead of accessing full Post object I could have simply tested the existence of post by running a count query, but since I need post attributes so I have to get full object.

It feels to me that maybe my url scheme is not that good or there is something better that can be done here!

Can anyone tell me if and how this can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Your url schema is okay and should work great for search engines. You cloud use a query like this with [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.get_or_404):

```
title, posted_on = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id).values(Post.title, Post.posted_on)
```

I cloud not test it but it should work and raise a HTTP 404 error by a not existing post. Also there should only a transfere of title and posted_on data without the full posting.